# swfembed not working

Tags: jquery, flash, swfobject

i'm having a problem with embedding a full screen flash gallery.
when clicking a thumbnail executes swfobject.embedSWF which creates the flash-object and the gallery is showing up.
when closing the flashgallery, i'm removing the whole flash-objects.
then when clicking another thumbnail, swfobject.embedSWF for embedding the object simply doesn't work anymore
what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you add your code .... please please please

Answer (score 0):

When you use SWFObject, your target element (commonly a div) will be **replaced** by the <object> generated by SWFObject.

If you remove your SWF then try to embed a new SWF using the same target ID, you will find your target no longer exists -- there is no longer an HTML element with that ID.

What you'll need to do is use a script to re-create the element before attempting to perform your second embed.

There's a tutorial and example on that topic here:
http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/load-a-swf-using-javascript-onclick-event/

(See "Replacing a loaded SWF with another SWF")